# How to create a program for randomly assign 0 and 1 to array elements and find the decimal value for it

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this code to find decimal values of 8 bits representation in sign magnitude. So I created an array and randomly assign values to it between 0-1, then prints the bit pattern and the true decimal value for it. Is there any easy way to do than this in Java?

```
import java.util.Random;

class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int A[] = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            int count = 1, k = 6, l = 0, m = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                A[i] = r.nextInt(2);
                System.out.print(A[i]);
                if (count == 1) {
                    if (A[i] == 1) {
                        m = -A[i];
                    } else {
                        m = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    double d = Math.pow(2, k);
                    l += (int) d * A[i];
                    k--;
                }
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(" = " + (l * m));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try, make a random binary string and then convert this string to a decimal value using JAVA's string to decimal converter, Integer.parseInt(string,base), here is an example:`

```
String randBinaryNumber;
char sign;

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
// creates binary string 
randBinaryNumber += Integer.toString(r.nextInt(2));
}
//gets sign of randBinaryNumber
sign = randBinaryNumber.charAt(0);

// removes first character of string
randBinaryNumber = randBinaryNumber.substring(1);

// converts string to decimal
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(randBinaryNumber,2);

if(sign == '1')
  decimal *=-1;
```

Something like this should work, if you have any problems leave a comment.

EDIT: Using string concatenation in a for loop is bad practise as it creates a new object for ever iteration. 
Instead you should use the string builder class to append.

you should add:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 randBinaryNumber = sb.append(r.nextInt(2));
```

instead of:

```
 randBinaryNumber += Integer.toString(r.nextInt(2));
```

This stores your string value in one object instead of making a new object everytime you add a binary digit.